# How to Add Social networking buttons to Magento

Tags: magento, magento-1.7, magento-1.4, magento-1.5

I have a magento version of 1.7.0.2. I have tried to add social networking buttons to products as to share the product details, But I dont know whether it is working or not also. I have installed an extension [Here is a link of extension](http://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/social-bookmark-icons-7376.html#tab%3areviews) . But in that site in the overview tab, they said that we have to copy and paste some code on which html page we would like to see. But the code is missing there..

In the reviews section one guy mentioned the process. I have gone through that also, But no use. Can anyone know a better option than this??

Answer (score 1):

Try add the code below your template file

```
<?php echo Mage::helper('network/data')->CUE_socialIcons(); ?>
```

See http://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/social-bookmark-icons-7376.html#tab%3areviews

Comment: Thanks for ur answer.. I did the same thing, But no use.. But I got the answer. I got it from [sharethis.com](www.sharethis.com).. From there I have collected my require answer..

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php echo CUE_socialIcons(); ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

We can easily add social icons from http://www.addthis.com and http://www.sharethis.com . We can customize the social networks which are required. I don't prefer any extensions to do this. We can make it easily.

As I mentioned above that I am using an extension, later on, I uninstalled the extension and got the social icons from addthis.com. Just we need to register and follow the steps as shown in those sites.